# MSFT enterprise library and ADO.NET

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, enterprise

Actually we're using Enterprise data accessing logic in our application but currently solution having lot of logic for data connection for accessing SQL database but we are planning to move the same on cloud and we analyzed the changes but stuck on these points:

- There are lot of transientfaults in database on cloud, we think of Transient error handling block and also the ADO.NET 4.5.2 latest inbuilt retry logic but after lot of google not found something that stated by MSFT in ADO.NET as we doesn't wants to change the logic in our Data access. if ADO.NET supports the Transient faults.
- Or there is any other approach we have to think about?

all suggestions will be really appreciated!

Comment: Enterprise library is an abandoned framework. Any reason why you are using it still?

Comment: Yes i agree but we doesn't want to change the old code as the changes are in bulk, any approach we can have so the old code untouched and we can apply transient handling? like [mentioned here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I recommend you look into using Polly. https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly

Comment: i created fault handling block but wants to know is anything there which is inbuilt in ADO.NET latest versions as MSFT saying so

Comment: That link your provided is related to connection pooling. If you need to build in some retry logic, then I recommend you use Polly. https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enterprise.transientfaulthandling package did it well it runs a code block inside a wrapper that handles the sql transient errors and retry at his own, better than polly.